# WPF Prism Assembly StrongNaming

Tags: wpf, assemblies, prism

I am trying to strong name my WPF assemblies to add to the GAC. I have references to the to the prim assemblies in my project and the compilation fails with

> Error 1   Assembly generation failed -- Referenced assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation' does not have a strong name

What am I missing? I do understand what is happening here but I dont think its a good idea to sign the prism assemblies myself. What does everyone else do in such (or similar) situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not up to speed with Prism, but is this a release version?

Anyway, if the authors didn't strong-name their assemblies they did not intend their assemblies *and derived ones* to be put in the GAC.

And maybe you should just re-think that decision, the GAC should be used very rarely.

Comment: *To Add to this: Unless you are installing multiple applications on the client that use the same libraries, don't touch the GAC, no need.

Comment: The way it works there are certain assemblies in Prism that need to be built from source(which are unsigned). I am guessing 90% of the audience is not going to modify the source and use the library as is if only to avoid maintainence hassel. So I think there should be MS signed versions in the first place. But since they are not I am stuck with either dropping GAC'ing or signing them myself(the latter very surprisingly seems to be the general recommendation on MSDN)

Comment: @Tom. The app is likely to be called from multiple applications in a suite so GAC'ing is indeed a necessity.

Comment: NVM, using it in multiple apps does _not_ necessitate the GAC.  You only need the GAC when your lib is going to have its own independent release cycle with publisher policies. Otherwise, just install multiple copies.